# Why am I getting this error when I try to type Text() or Image() in Button(action: {})?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I started learning Swift 3 days ago and I think you will understand it. But every time I want to put a Text or Image to the Button, It gives me this error:

Result of 'Image' initializer is unused / Result of 'Text' initializer is unused

This is driving me crazy and I am trying to search for help but everybody describes it in a professional way. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a warnign and not like a error, try compiling your code, it should work

Comment: Do not post pictures of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the Image in the action block of the button, which is the stuff do do when the button is tapped. It's not the place to put the content of the button.

```
    Button(action: {
      print("Pressed")
    }) {
        Image("someImageName")
    }
```

The error message means something like you computed some thing, but then did nothing with that result. For example `3+4` would compute 7 and then just do nothing with the 7. But `print(3+4)` would do something with the 7. It's suspicious to compute something for no reason, so XCode warns you.

Comment: The Image I put wasn't the content of the button. I wanted that image to pop up when the button is pressed. That's why I put it in action: {}.

Comment: The action block contains just regular swift code, "*do* this, then *do* that". The stuff in a swift UI View is a "ViewBuilder" block, which says "The view *IS* this list of stuff" - can't mix and match, don't confuse them. Suggest find a tutorial showing example like what you want to do. Try https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/showing-and-hiding-views-with-transitions

Answer (score 0):

//For set text to button

```
btnTest.setTitle("Your text", for: .normal)
```

//For set icon to button

```
btnTest.setImage(UIImage(named: "Your Imgae name"), for: .normal)
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not I am asking for. A user told me to remove the screenshot of the code. So that's why the question isn't clear. 

When I want to display an image / text by tapping a button, it gives me the error above and the image / text doesn't appear.